# Blank screen with apple-mobile-web-app-capable and Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

We've got a few pages that use the apple-mobile-web-app-capable meta tag (value="yes"), but on a login page that allows Facebook Connect, you get a blank page when you click on the connect button. I've seen this posted on the old FB developer forums, but with no relevant responses. Has anyone figured this out already?

Comment: Tumbleweed achieved, I guess nobody is using this meta tag?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found anything on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a bug in facebooks API. I don't think they've tested their API in iPhone web app mode. Issue can be followed here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/317323871621290

The issue have been raised here on Stack Overflow a couple of times too:
[How do I get back to the iPhone web app after having logged in with Facebook Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604960/how-do-i-get-back-to-the-iphone-web-app-after-having-logged-in-with-facebook-con)

[blank white screen after FB login via web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019798/blank-white-screen-after-fb-login-via-web-app)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Johan. I've linked back to this from the Facebook bug page you cited.

Comment: The bug info is not available anymore