# Blank screen with Mobile Web App and Facebook Connect

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, webview, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am building a web app that can open full-screen on iPhone and am following the code for Facebook mobile web, which can be found at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/

When I try to login using the Facebook login page, I get a blank white screen after I click the "login" button. The user IS logged in though.. I know this because if I close and reopen the web app, I check the login status and try to get some user info, and it works fine.

I have seen others with the same here: [blank white screen after FB login via web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019798/blank-white-screen-after-fb-login-via-web-app)

It seems that somebody has identified a workaround, but I cannot get it to work. The code I am using is:

```
   function loginUser() {    
     FB.login(function(response) { }, {scope:'email'});    
     }
```

Others have indicated that I need to utilize the workaround here:

```
login({scope:'email', redirect_uri:'where_to_go_when_login_ends'})
```

Does anyone know how to merge these pieces of code to get it to work?

Thanks!

Comment: if you are using the facebook app on the phone for the login try closing it down fully and try again, sometimes I've seen that it gets confused.

Comment: Thanks for the reply peterept, that doesn't seem to be the issue though. Not too sure whats going on with it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the fact that the login window normally opens as a pop-up window. However, in (iOS) web apps this is not properly supported for some reason.

By providing a normal link instead of FB's own login btn script, the login process stays within the same window (including the redirect process!)

I hope this helps anyone...

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL&state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE&scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES">LOGIN!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197668/fb-login-broken-flow-for-ios-webapp), it worked for me :

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    //deal with response
}, {scope:'permissions', redirect_uri:'url to redirect to'} );
```

Comment: I believe this undocumented feature may have been removed by Facebook. I was using this workaround and it recently stopped working for me, leaving me with the blank white screen. This alternative method appears to work on an iPad1 with iOS5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197668/fb-login-broken-flow-for-ios-webapp