# How to get FirebaseSimpleLogin Facebook login working in a fullscreen/homescreen iOS Web App

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I have an angular app that painlessly integrates with Firebase's SimpleLogin service for Facebook on the web, however, it relies on opening a pop-up to do so.

Although iOS 7.0.3 seems to have fixed some severe bugs where alerts and popups were not functional in fullscreen web apps (i.e. after 'Add to Homescreen'-ing a website via Safari), the Facebook login fails after redirecting to Facebook and granting approval, landing back on a blank page (which requires an app restart to remove).

I suspect this has something to do with the was Facebook is redirecting back, but AFAIK I don't have control over that, nor would [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019798/blank-white-screen-after-fb-login-via-web-app) [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197668/fb-login-broken-flow-for-ios-webapp) [these](http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/facebook-login-not-working-in-web-app-mode-ios) fix this.

Are there any workaround that exist for this problem?

Comment: [Engineer at Firebase] I'd be happy to look into this issue for you. When you get a moment, can you let me know if you are using any iOS-specific meta-tags in your application, and if so, what your current settings are?

Comment: @RobDiMarco No iOS-specific meta tags. Or, at least, I don't know what those are :)

Comment: It looks like this flow restricts the use of popups, and we'll need to implement a redirect-based auth. flow to support this environment. I have opened a bug at [https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login/issues/7](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login/issues/7) to track this issue and get it resolved for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Engineer at Firebase] Support for redirect-based OAuth has been added to the Firebase Simple Login Web Client as of v1.3.0, available from the [Firebase CDN](https://www.firebase.com/docs/downloads.html) or via Bower using `bower install firebase-simple-login`.

This update enables the Firebase Simple Login client to detect iOS "standalone" applications and handle the redirect-based OAuth automatically in your application.