# Error/blank page with Chrome and Safar browser apps for iphone when using javascript FB login code

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, facebook-javascript-sdk, parse-platform

UPDATE:

This issue is affecting both Chrome and safari browser apps.

I'm trying to use Facebook login (Javascript/Parse) on my site with the following code. It works fine in the PC browser.

Issue with Chrome app

> Error, unsupported Browser: Google Chrome for iOS does not support
>   this feature. Please use Safari and try again

It stops on the follwing url (Ive changed sensitive data to XXXX).

https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id=XXXX&client_id=XXXX&display=touch&domain=kudosoo.com&e2e=%7B%7D&locale=en_US&origin=2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D40%23cb%3Df2562075ac%26domain%3DXXXX.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fkudosoo.com%252Ff3714a6424%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df2a549beb4&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&sdk=joey

Issue with safari app

It stops on the page that has my script to execute the login scripts, even with a browser refresh it does not move past this page and does not log the user in.

---

I've seen some posts here [FB.login broken flow for iOS WebApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197668/fb-login-broken-flow-for-ios-webapp) , but unsure if they will resolve it or where to place the code?

My code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>

<!-- Runs Parse and FB code that uses Facebook authentication to login user to the site and redirects them to the main content area. This page is fired from the Facebook button being clicked on the site landing page-->


<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <title>Fb Login</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.16.min.js"></script>   


</head>
<body>

    <!-- Important, must be on the page -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>    


    <!-- Initialize the Parse object-->
    <script type="text/javascript">     
    Parse.initialize("XXX", "XXX");


//Fb app information//

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
        appId      : 'XXX',
        channelUrl : 'http://XXXX/channel.html',
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
    });

//FB user authentication script, after this completes it fires todos_two.js to redirect user to main content page//

Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
    success: function(user) {
        if (!user.existed()) {
            alert("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
            window.location.href="user_home.html";
        } else {
            alert("User logged in through Facebook!");
            window.location.href="user_home.html";
        }
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
        alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
    }
});


};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using the Chrome browser on iOS or are you using Safari?

Comment: @jackslash yes, is that a known problem?

Answer (score 1):

So in the comments you say you are using chrome. The error message is pretty clear:

> Error, unsupported Browser: Google Chrome for iOS does not support this feature. Please use Safari and try again

Chrome is unsupported. You have to use safari to use Facebook login.

I'm going to assume that you're smart enough to have figured this out and that what you are really asking is WHY this is the case. The answer to that question is found by Googling.

[Facebook OAuth "Unsupported" in Chrome on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843116/facebook-oauth-unsupported-in-chrome-on-ios)

Leads us to [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=237084) which tells us there is a bug in chrome for iOS that prevents it from working properly.

You can work around this issue by using a redirect based login flow with this documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: Thanks for taking time to write a detailed response. As you may have guessed I'm learning and therefore my skill set is not as great as other peoples.. Based on the link, is it just a case of using this code in the above ? https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id={app-id}
   &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is in two parts.

Firstly, the issue with Chrome is as per @jackslash comments in his answer.

Secondly, the code uses alerts to notify the user once the login has completed successfully. Within safari on the iphone, even with tweaking the browser settings this is an issue. I resolved it by removing the alerts from the code completely. After that the login process functioned as required.