# Blank Screen with Mobile Web App with Facebook Connect

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, webview, facebook-javascript-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [blank white screen after FB login via web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019798/blank-white-screen-after-fb-login-via-web-app)

I am building a web app that can open full-screen on iPhone and am following the code for Facebook mobile web, which can be found at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/

When I try to login using the Facebook login page, I get a blank white screen after I click the "login" button. The user IS logged in though.. I know this because if I close and reopen the web app, I check the login status and try to get some user info, and it works fine.

I have seen others with the same here: [blank white screen after FB login via web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019798/blank-white-screen-after-fb-login-via-web-app)

It seems that somebody has identified a workaround, but I cannot get it to work. The code I am using is:

```
   function loginUser() {    
     FB.login(function(response) { }, {scope:'email'});    
     }
```

Others have indicated that I need to utilize the workaround here:

```
login({scope:'email', redirect_uri:'where_to_go_when_login_ends'})
```

Does anyone know how to merge these pieces of code to get it to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you post an exact copy of a question that's already on the site and even link to it?? If you have further questions regarding the answers you should have posted on that other question. Here's the solution: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/ (Client-side authentication - self contained example)

Answer (score 1):

This should work: 
function loginUser(){
    FB.login(function(response) { }, {scope:'email', redirect_uri:'http://your-redirect-url'});
}