# Google+ sign in giving blank page iOS web app

Tags: ios, google-plus, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have an issue with using the interactive post from the Google+ api when using the iOS web app view. In safari or any other browser on iOS or Android there's no problem logging into Google+ and sharing the post but in web app mode of iOS it throws a white page as soon as you fill in your credentials and click "log in" on the Google sign in page it gives you.

I use this to define the mobile web view:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
```

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: I am not sure if the issues are exactly the same but perhaps this question has something for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019798/blank-white-screen-after-fb-login-via-web-app

Comment: It seems like the same problem but the facebook implementation of things is totally different from the Google one so there's not really a solution there for me.